# iOS: Video playback in large frame with UIScrollView ticker

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I'm creating an app that wants to have full screen type resolution for video playback on iPad (i.e. 1024x768).  On top of this player I want a scrolling ticker (currently a UIScrollView with many subviews).

If the player is small (256x192), the scrollview is very performant.  But if I go 512x384 its performance seems to degrade, right up to 1024x768 where the scrollview performs terribly.

Is this just an obvious limitation with video playback/UIKit? Is there any optimisation I can do or other objects to experiment with?

[edit]

I disabled the scrolling ticker to ensure this wasn't the problem and added a simple small UIView with the following animation method on button press:

```
`[UIView animateWithDuration:.5 delay:0 usingSpringWithDamping:1.0f initialSpringVelocity:1.0f options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut animations:^{
    int Xrand = arc4random() % 1024;
    int Yrand = arc4random() % 768;
    self.animationView.center = CGPointMake(Xrand, Yrand);
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.reportbtn];
} completion:nil];`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was just slow in the simulator. Tested it on iPad 2/4 and it worked fine ;)

Answer (score 0):

Having 300 odd images loaded into the memory along with video playbac can get heavy on the device.

What you can do is replace the scrollview with something that reuses the views and thus reducing the overall memory footprint.

You can consider using `UICollectionview` or a simple solution NickLookwood's [SwipeView](https://github.com/nicklockwood/SwipeView). Both allow reusing of the views.

Comment: That's not a bad piece of advice, but UICollectionView doesn't seem to work when the user isn't interacting with it.  What I mean is if you set a collectionview to set content offset within an animateWithDuration block it doesn't dequeue cells properly.

Comment: As a test, I added a simple button to move a rect randomly around the screen.  With the UIScrollView disabled and just video playback at 1024x768 this animate grinds to a very juttery slow speed: